# After the last match is found, how do I make the loop stop

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have is matching certain criteria's and based on that copying them from an import page to an output page. It is working in the sense that it is finding all the right matches. However, the last match it finds it is returning that 3 times instead of just 1 time. How do I make the loop stop immediately after the last match is found?

I do have to note that my knowledge regarding VBA is pretty limited. This code was produced with the help of forum members here.

If required I could submit the excel file as well, if that makes things easier.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wsImport As Worksheet

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsSpec As Worksheet
    
    Set wsImport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    Set wsSpec = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Specifications")
    
    Dim CriteriaA As String, CriteriaB As String, CriteriaC As String
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim origin As String, KeyToFind As String
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim strAdress As String
    
    With wsSpec
        CriteriaA = wsImport.Range("C3").Value2
        CriteriaB = wsImport.Range("C4").Value2
        CriteriaC = wsImport.Range("C5").Value2
        
        Set rngDB = .Range("h1", .Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       
        Set aCell = rngDB.Find(What:=CriteriaA, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            strAdress = aCell.Address
            Do
                If aCell.Offset(, 1).Value2 = CriteriaB And _
                   aCell.Offset(, 2).Value2 = CriteriaC Then
                   origin = aCell.Offset(, 6).Value2
                   KeyToFind = aCell.Offset(, 7).Value2
                End If
                If origin = "Letters" Then
                    CopyRows "M", KeyToFind, True
                ElseIf origin = "Numbers" Then
                    CopyRows "H", KeyToFind, False
                End If
                 Set aCell = rngDB.FindNext(aCell)
            Loop While aCell.Address <> strAdress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub CopyRows(Col As String, SearchString As String, PartialString As Boolean)
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
     
    With wsImport
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        lRow = .Range(Col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range(Col & "1:" & Col & lRow)
            If PartialString = False Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SearchString
            Else
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & SearchString & "*"
            End If
            
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
   
    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If Not copyFrom Is Nothing Then
        If wsOutput.Range("A1") = "" Then
                copyFrom.Copy wsOutput.Range("A1")
        Else
                copyFrom.Copy wsOutput.Range("a" & LastRow)(2)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:
Per request screenshots:

Import:
[image: Import]
Specifications:
[image: Specifications]

Comment: LastRow = wsOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Forgive me i dont fully appreciate yet what the code does, but it strikes me this might more easily be done using `autofilter`? If as an experiment you can apply filters to your sheet and leave only the rows you care about then you can do that programmatically and manipulate the filtered rows using `Range.SpecialCells`

Comment: @Dy.Lee Still doing the same after I applied that.

Comment: @JohnnieL it is using autofilter and specialcells actually.

Comment: oh sorry my bad i didnt scroll down

Comment: could you post a screenshot of import and specifications? tks

Comment: @JohnnieL I did. Both the pages have more rows, but I guess this should do the trick.

Comment: at the top of your "do" loop you are not initialising `origin` so if you do not trigger the if clause `If aCell.Offset(, 1).Value2 = CriteriaB And _aCell.Offset(, 2).Value2 = CriteriaC Then` your code will process `If origin = "Letters" Then` etc based on the value set previously. is that what you want to happen?

Comment: @JohnnieL if Criteria A+B+C are met, the code should look in the same table for Origin which is "Studentnumber Type" if that is Letters or Numbers, based on that it will take the "Key" from "Studentnumber" and look at the import page where it can find it. For "Letters" it will look on import page column H, for numbers column M. Then it has to look for all those keys that match those criteria's. At least, that's what it is supposed to do.

Comment: could you add the coumn headings to the screen cap? they are xplicitly referenced so would be helpful: my earlier point - you are looping through specifications column h (city?) finding matches for criterion A. if you then match on critrion B and C you set `origin`. If you dont get a match, you ***dont*** set/reset origin but you still copy that row based on the previous setting of `origin`

Comment: @JohnnieL you are completely right! That seemed to do the trick. Thanks a lot for the help man! I put the If letters/numbers statements inside the criteria if statement and now it works perfectly.

Comment: great - appreciate the "tick" :) also the `With wsSpec` doesnt really do anything, i would remove that block and just have `Set rngDB = wsSpec.Range("h1", wsSpec.Range("h" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` and set some white space free

Comment: @JohnnieL you are right. I edited that as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so in your data, row 1 `london/university/old` doesnt match criteria B and C and so `copyrow` will not be called because at this stage `origin` is empty. Your last 4 rows, 2 match criterion A but will not match Criterion B and C and so will all be copied with `origin` = "letters" because that was the last time `origin` was set (criteria B and C met) so I think that must be why you are getting multiple copies at the end. You need your `if "letters"/if "numbers"` code inside the `if criteria b and c met` code - thats why you are getting the last one 3 times

```
            If aCell.Offset(, 1).Value2 = CriteriaB And _
                aCell.Offset(, 2).Value2 = CriteriaC Then
                origin = aCell.Offset(, 6).Value2
                KeyToFind = aCell.Offset(, 7).Value2
                If origin = "Letters" Then
                    CopyRows "M", KeyToFind, True
                ElseIf origin = "Numbers" Then
                    CopyRows "H", KeyToFind, False
                End If
            End If
```